# https and 443 together in Uri C#

Tags: c#, serialization, https, uri

.Net Core 3.1, HttpWebRequest

Hi!

I need to request some URL **https**://domain:**443**/something (outer requirement), but Uri.ToString() remove port from Uri.

As result i need to get "POST **https**://domain:**443**/something HTTP/1.1"

Thank you!

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need port number 443 in the url? It’s default port number for https.

Comment: Warning! [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netcore-3.1) is obsolete. Use `HttpClient` instead. Additionally suggested class is working faster.

Answer (score 0):

> The string returned by this method does not contain port information when the port is the default port for the scheme.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.tostring?view=netcore-3.1

If you were to set the port to something over than 443 and then call `ToString()` then the port number would be displayed.

The `OriginalString` property on `Uri` will show you the original string passed to the constructor (with the port number).

Edit: the port is still stored on the `Uri` object, it's just not displayed by `ToString()`; if you look at the value of the `Port` property on the `Uri` you'll see it's set to 423.  Using this `Uri` object in a `HttpWebRequest` will result in the request being issued on port 443.

As others have said if you are using port 443 then you don't need to worry about all of this because port 443 is the default port for https.

Comment: Thank you, Simon! I need to use it further in HttpWebRequest (https and 443)

Comment: It's right, but this Uri as a string `"POST https://domain/something HTTP/1.1"` won't contain a port number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building Uri yourself you can use the following code which always returns what you originally passed to your constructor:

```
var myUri = new Uri("https://domain:443/something");
var myString = myUri.OriginalString;
```

Comment: Thank you, Sina,
but I need to use it in HttpWebRequest

Comment: @Gasan: If your variable is `HttpWebRequest myRequest` then `myRequest.RequestUri.OriginalString` is what you need.